# Set of elements in $K$ that are purely inseparable over $F$ is a subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $F\subset K$ be an algebraic field extension. Is the set of all elements of $K$ that are purely inseparable over $F$ necessarily a subfield of $K$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. An element $a\in K$ is purely inseparable iff $a^{p^n}\in F$ for some $n\geq 0$ (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension#Purely_inseparable_extensions)). Let $E$ be the subset of purely inseparable elements of $K$. For any $a,b\in E$, we have $a^{p^n}\in F$ and $b^{p^m}\in F$ for some $n,m\geq0$, so
$$(-a)^{p^n}\in F\hskip 0.5in (a^{-1})^{p^n}=1/(a^{p^n})\in F$$
$$(a+b)^{p^{n+m}}=a^{p^{n+m}}+b^{p^{n+m}}=(a^{p^n})^{p^m}+(b^{p^m})^{p^n}\in F$$
and
$$(ab)^{p^{n+m}}=a^{p^{n+m}}b^{p^{n+m}}=(a^{p^n})^{p^m}(b^{p^m})^{p^n}\in F$$
Thus, $E$ is a subfield.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. This is clearer if you use the following definition of pure inseparability: an element $\alpha$ of an algebraic extension $F/K$ is purely inseparable if $|\text{Hom}_K(K(\alpha), \bar{K})| = 1$. Now it is obvious that if $\alpha, \beta$ are purely inseparable then any $K$-homomorphism $K(\alpha, \beta) \to \bar{K}$ is determined by what it does to $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so is unique.

Comment: The $\hom$ is the set of $K$-linear *field* homomorphisms, I guess :)