# Elements of $K$ which are separable over $F$ form a subfield of $K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> If $K$ is an extension of $F$ prove that the set of elements in $K$ which are separable over $F$ forms a subfield of $K$.

I have a proof for the set of *algebraic* elements in $K$ forming a subfield, but I'm stuck with the separable elements.

I'm assuming I should be splitting this into cases of characteristic = 0 and characteristic $\neq$ 0. Any help? I'm at a loss.

Comment: It's also true that [the elements which are purely inseparable over $F$ form a subfield of $K$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26778/purely-inseparable-extension).

Answer (score 4):

Characteristic $0$ is immediate, since all elements are separable (irreducible polynomial has no repeated roots).

For characteristic $p$, let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be separable. The characteristic polynomial of $\beta$ over $F(\alpha)$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $\beta$ over $F$, hence has no repeated roots; so $\beta$ is separable over $F(\alpha)$. Now consider the tower $F\subseteq F(\alpha+\beta)\subseteq F(\alpha,\beta)$. Looking at the separable degrees, we have:
$$[F(\alpha,\beta):F]_s = [F(\alpha,\beta),F(\alpha+\beta)]_s[F(\alpha+\beta):F]_s.$$
But 
$$[F(\alpha,\beta):F]_s = [F(\alpha,\beta):F(\alpha)]_s[F(\alpha):F]_s = [F(\alpha,\beta):F(\alpha)][F(\alpha):F] = [F(\alpha,\beta):F],$$ 
and $[F(\alpha,\beta):F(\alpha+\beta)]_s\leq [F(\alpha,\beta):F(\alpha+\beta)]$, $[F(\alpha+\beta):F]_s \leq [F(\alpha+\beta):F]$. So in order to get
$$\begin{align*}
[F(\alpha,\beta):F]&=[F(\alpha,\beta):F]_s \\
&= [F(\alpha,\beta),F(\alpha+\beta)]_s[F(\alpha+\beta):F]_s\\
&\leq [F(\alpha,\beta):F(\alpha+\beta)][F(\alpha+\beta):F]\\ 
&= [F(\alpha,\beta):F],\end{align*}$$
we must have equality throughout, hence $\alpha+\beta$ is separable over $F$. The same argument holds for $\alpha\beta$.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm also wondering if there's a way to argue without using degree-arguments. This answer is very helpful though.

Comment: Dear Arturo, I think there is some problem in your proof because $F(\alpha)\subseteq F(\alpha+\beta)$ doesn't hold in general (take $\beta=-\alpha$).

Comment: @QiL: Oops; that should be $F$ itself. Thanks!

Comment: @peter: First, there was a mistake, as noted by QiL; it's been fixed. As to your question: what precisely is your definition of separable? there are many equivalent ways of defining it. You could show that $\alpha+\beta$ is separable over $F(\alpha)$ (its irreducible polynomial is a translate of the irreducible of $\beta$) and then use the same constructive argument used to prove algebraic extension of algebraic extension is algebraic to show $\alpha+\beta$ satisfies a polynomial with no repeated roots and coefficients in $F$. Similarly with $\alpha\beta$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin What about inverse elements?

Comment: @JhonDoe: Inverse elements are automatic, since $F(\alpha)=F[\alpha]\$ for algebraic elements.