# Composite of two purely inseparable extensions is purely inseparable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L,F$ be extensions of the field $K$ and are contained in a common field. Prove that, if $L$ and $F$ are purely inseparable extensions over $K$ then $LF$ is also a purely inseparable extension over $K$. Is the converse true?

How do I prove it?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume the characteristic of your fields is $p>0$. You want to prove that, for a field extension $L/K$, the set $L^\prime$ of elements of $L$ that are purely inseparable over $K$ is a subfield of $L$. You do this with the following characterization of pure inseparability: an element $x\in L$ is purely inseparable over $K$ if and only if, for some integer $n\geq 0$, $x^{p^n}\in K$. A proof of this fact can be found here: [Purely inseparable extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26778/purely-inseparable-extension).

With this, your result can be proved as follows. Consider the *subfield* $E$ of $LF$ consisting of elements purely inseparable over $K$. Because $L$ and $F$ are both purely inseparable over $K$, $L,F\subseteq E$, so $LF\subseteq E$, and thus $LF=E$ is purely inseparable over $K$.

The converse is also true. More generally, if $K\subseteq L\subseteq E$ and $E/K$ is purely inseparable, then $L/K$ is purely inseparable. This is immediate from the definition of pure inseparability.

Comment: Thank you for your support.

Comment: How about Galois extension? Do we have the same result?

Comment: It's true that a compositum of two Galois extensions of $K$ is Galois over $K$, but it's not true that a subextension of a Galois extension is Galois.

Comment: "This is immediate from the definition of pure inseparability" Which one?

Answer (score 2):

Proposition:

> The class of purely inseparable extensions is distinguished.

*Proof*. Let $k\subset F\subset E$. Suppose that $E/k$ is purely inseparable. Every element of $F$ lies in $E$ and is therefore purely inseparable, so $F/k$ is purely inseparable. The minimal polynomial of any $\alpha\in E$ over $F$ divides its minimal polynomial over $k$, which is of the form $x^{p^n}-a$, which factors in $k^a$ into $(x-\alpha)^{p^n}$. A polynomial of form $(x-\alpha)^{p^kr}$ where $r$ is prime to $p$ may be written as $(x^{p^k}-\alpha^{p^k})^r$, and upon expanding the binomial, one sees the coefficient of the $(x^{p^k})^{r-1}$ term is $r\alpha^{p^k}=0$. Since $r\ne 0$, we must have $\alpha^{p^k}=0$, so any irreducible factor of $x^{p^n}-a$ must be of the form $x^{p^k}-a$. Hence the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ is of this form, and $E$ is then purely inseparable over $F$.

Conversely, suppose that $F/k$ is purely inseparable and $E/F$ is purely inseparable. Then for any $\alpha\in E, a=\alpha^{p^n}\in F$ for some $n$, and then $a^{p^m}=(\alpha^{p^n})^{p^m}=\alpha^{p^{n+m}}\in E$ for some $m$. Thus $E/k$ is purely inseparable.

If $K/k$ and $L/k$ are extensions of $k$ and $K$ is purely inseparable over $k$, then $KL$ is generated over $L$ for a set of elements in $K$, and thus they are purely inseparable over $L$. Then $KL$ is purely inseparable over $L$.

Using the towers $K\subset L\subset LF, K\subset F\subset LF$ and the above proposition, it follows that $LF/K$ is purely inseparable iff $F/K$ and $L/K$ are both purely inseparable.